# How to allow permission for Story testing

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am trying to develop some stories to test my Bixby capsule. The thing is that every time I clear cache or create a new story, I always end up with an error of **1 Cache miss**. According to Bixby Studio, this is caused by the capsule from be locked by the permission request, preventing the story from finishing.

I have been looking at the Bixby documentations, but there isn't a solution to be found.

What is to be expected is the story to approve the permission request, otherwise, continue on with the story.

Comment: This doesn't sound right.  Can you provide the specific permission request that you are making in the capsule.bxb file?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound right.  Can you provide the specific permission request that you are making in the capsule.bxb file?

Comment: It's not based on the permission given by the capsule.bxb, it's allowing the stories (used for testing) to automatically agree on the permissions asked (after you clear story cache). The permission page is what causes the stories to stop.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine creating story using simulator's "export story" function.

1. clear or reset learning->"selection learning" in simulator window
2. start the story flow, either accept or reject permission and continue with utterance.
3. click "export story" at the lower right corner of simulator window at the end of story flow to save.

For example, the **Yes** to permission request should be saved as the following intent.

```
intent { goal { viv.core.ServicePermissionResponse {
        accessGranted { viv.core.Boolean(true) }
        persist { viv.core.Boolean(false) }
      } } }
```